# Jquery and IE8 animate opacity solution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to animate opacity with Jquery an it is working fine in every browser except, you guess it dreaded **IE8**!
 Problem: on animation I am seeing some ugly artifacts:(

I know that I can solve this by removing background and adding the same background color to my animated div and to my container div,but it is **NOT** an option in my case. 
Can somebody suggest solution to this? 
My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".img").animate({
        opacity: 0
    });
    $(".glow").click(function() {
        $(".img").animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 5000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you considered using fadeTo instead? (Not sure if that is accomplishing what you're looking for.)

Comment: Looks more like a clearfix problem to me, as jQuery irons out the opacity issues in IE. For some reason it's just fine in IE8 mode (using IE9) here ?

Comment: http://www.kevinleary.net/jquery-fadein-fadeout-problems-in-internet-explorer/  <-- check this site for a fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding IE filters to my CSS I have partially solved this issue (**much** better now and no black halo).

Lost whole day with this so I hope it will help someone more fortunate than me:)

```
 .img{
 display:block;
 width:230px;
 height:300px;
 owerflow:hidden;
 position:relative;
 outline:none;

 /*Notice (ugly) IE filter here and Source to my PNG image */

 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=http://www.robertpeic.com/glow/glow.png) alpha(opacity=0);
 background:none;
 margin:0px auto;
 padding-top:10px;

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's what you get when you change opacity of the images with alpha transparency in IE7 and IE8. There is another question about the same [IE GIF/PNG Transparency issue with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634094/ie-gif-png-transparency-issue-with-jquery)